# Getting and storing PHP session variable from database depending on user level

Tags: php, mysql

I have a login page which redirects users to different sections of the website depending on their user level. The `users` table, does not have their first and last names. It contains their idnumber and password and a few other columns.

The first and last names of the users are stored in various tables depending on their user level. For example, in the `teachers` table, it has the first names etc, and also in the students table.

I want to get the logged in user's name and store it in a session variable so I can output things like "Hi, John".

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this, or am I on the right track?

**Code Excerpt**

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $idnumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user-name']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user-password']);
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE idnumber = '" . $idnumber . "' and password = '" . md5($password) . "'");

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $_SESSION['usr_id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
        $_SESSION['userlevel'] = $row['userlevel'];
        $_SESSION['idnumber'] = $row['idnumber'];
        echo $_SESSION['usr_id'];
        
        if ($_SESSION['userlevel']=="1"){
            $loggedinusername = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT a.idnumber, b.firstnames, b.surname FROM users a LEFT JOIN educationdirectors b ON a.idnumber=b.idnumber WHERE idnumber = '" . $_SESSION['idnumber']. "'");
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($loggedinusername)) {
                $_SESSION['idnumber'] = $row['firstnames'];
                header("Location: v1/ued/");
            } 

        } 
        else
        if ($_SESSION['userlevel']=="2"){
            header("Location: v1/ced/");
        }
        
    } else {
        $errormsg = "Incorrect Email or Password!!!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason for this database design?  Users will all have names (unless you allow bots) so why not store the common attributes on this table.  This would leave the other tables (teacher) to store details about their roles not them as a person.

Comment: I initially had a different db design but ended up with this because the coding was easier with this design because I didn't constantly have to make joins for simple queries.

Comment: Once you fetch the user record to verify it, you should store the values you need in the session rather than continually fetch them from the database.